# IE hold on to an xlsx file after upload using input type file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, excel, typescript, internet-explorer

I'm trying to upload a xlsx file using input type="file" tag,

```
    <div class="innerCnt fill" ng-app="ExcelImport" ng-controller="excelImportCtrl">
    <div class="row">
        <label for="fileToUpload">Select a File to Upload</label><br />
        <input type="file" id="fileToUpload" multiple class="fileUploadSelector" on-file-change="addFiles"  />
    </div>
    <h4 id="uploadStatusLabel" class="uploadStatusLabel"></h4>
    <div id="uploadExcelStatusGrid">
        <table class="table-striped" ng-hide="!files[0]">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>File name</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th>Actions</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="file in files">
                    <td class="centerCell"><div>{{file.name}}</div></td>
                    <td class="centerCell"><div>{{file.status || 'Waiting for upload'}}</div></td>
                    <td class="centerCell"><div><a href="#" ng-if="!file.status" ng-click="removeFile($index)">Delete</a></div></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <input type="button" id="excelUploadButton" class="button blueBtn" ng-click="uploadFiles()" value="Upload" ng-disabled="excelUploading || !files[0]"/>
</div>
```

This is the ts file:

```
 appImport.directive('onFileChange', function () {

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var onChangeHandler = scope.$eval((attrs as any).onFileChange);
            element.bind('change', function () {
                scope.$apply(function () {
                    var files = (element[0] as any).files;
                    if (files) {
                        onChangeHandler(files);
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Here is the addfiles fn:

```
class ImportController {
    private scope: any;

    constructor($scope: ng.IScope) {
        this.scope = $scope as any;
        this.scope.files = []
        this.scope.addFiles = files => this.addFiles(files)
        this.scope.removeFile = idx => this.removeFile(idx);
    }

    private addFiles(files: FileList) {
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            this.scope.files.push(files.item(i))
        }
    }

    private removeFile(entryIdx: number) {
        this.scope.files.splice(entryIdx, 1)
    }
}
appImport.controller("excelImportCtrl", ImportController)
```

once I browse the file in IE,I open the file in excel and make some changes, after saving the file a temp file will be created in same directory.

Temp file will be deleted once I close the application.

I try same process with Chrome but there is no temp file.

Can anyone help me how to get rid of this temp file using IE?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please inform us, Which version of IE and MS Office you are using? Other thing I want to confirm with you is, Did you open the Excel file from IE popup or you open it directly in Excel app? It can be possible that Excel app creating this temp file for any processing purpose. If you are accessing the file using code than make sure you release it's object after completing your work. Also make sure that your file upload get completed before you access that file.

Comment: The issue happens in IE11. I'm using MS Office 2010. I upload the the file from browse pop up, and edit it in Excel app. Definitely the temp is created by Excel app, but the reason is that IE holds on to the file. once i close my IE the temp file will be deleted.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_fileupload_type

Comment: I try above link in my IE and Chrome, issue still happens. So i assume it's different behaviors of browsers with <input type=file.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35055123/ie-11-lock-the-file-when-using-html-input-file-tag

Comment: according to above link if i add document.getElementById("fileToUpload").value=""; to my code IE will release the file. This solution works on W3school sample. but not on my code. :(

Comment: Can you show us, What changes you had made to free the file from IE? It may help to narrow down the issue. for testing purpose, Try to flush that object which contains the file to check whether it solves the issue or not.

Comment: I add document.getElementById("fileToUpload").value=""; to my addfile fn after for loop.

Comment: Try to reset the files variable in your TS file also try to reset files in addfiles fn to check whether it release the file or not.

Comment: Tried but it doesn't work.